# Getting sprite by URL in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have list of urls (it contains image). I need to convert it to sprite in `LIBGDX`. How can i do it? for example url like this - `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADGmqu-Krm10pvcLx9MlffZK6f9DaQS3S8Afje3gRBk=s83-c-mo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpRequest` to download resources, if you then save them into a temporary file you can initialize your `Texture`, `TextureRegion`, `Sprite` or whatever like you normally do:

```
Net.HttpRequest request = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
request.setUrl("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADGmqu-Krm10pvcLx9MlffZK6f9DaQS3S8Afje3gRBk=s83-c-mo");
```

Then, in the `handleHttpResponse` callback you can save to a temp file:

```
final FileHandle tmpFile = FileHandle.tempFile("texture");
tmpFile.write(httpResponse.getResultAsStream(), false);
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        texture = new Texture(tmpFile);
    }
});
```

Note that you need to `postRunnable` back to your main thread as graphic resources needs to be loaded on the **OpenGL** thread.

A full working example of an application loading your resource might look like this:

```
package com.bornander.sandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Net;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class SandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 800 * aspectRatio);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f, 0.0f);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        Net.HttpRequest request = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
        request.setUrl("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADGmqu-Krm10pvcLx9MlffZK6f9DaQS3S8Afje3gRBk=s83-c-mo");
        Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void handleHttpResponse (Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                final FileHandle tmpFile = FileHandle.tempFile("texture");
                tmpFile.write(httpResponse.getResultAsStream(), false);
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        texture = new Texture(tmpFile);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failed (Throwable t) { Gdx.app.error("yourtag", "failed to load", t); }

            @Override
            public void cancelled () { Gdx.app.log("yourtag", "load cancelled"); }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        if (texture != null)
            batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);

        batch.end();
    }
}
```